# Doit-on mettre une majuscule au mot « chapitre » ?

Tags: majuscules, formatage

Quand dans un livre on fait référence à un chapitre, une section, une sous-section, une annexe, etc., doit-on mettre une majuscule ? Par exemple, doit-on référer « au Chapitre 2 » ou « au chapitre 2 » ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Après relecture de la section *Majuscules* du *bon usage* la réponse semble être **non**. Évidemment la notion de *règle* pour ce genre de considération est toujours douteuse, mais le [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=le+chapitre%2C+le+Chapitre&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cle%20chapitre%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cle%20Chapitre%3B%2Cc0) semble confirmer, même si on note quand même un léger usage de la majuscule.

Answer (score -1):

Non. La majuscule n'est pas nécessaire.

Comment: C'est vrai, mais je pense que plusieurs personnes n'ont pas apprécié cette affirmation préemptoire. Une justification, par exemple en citant un manuel de style ou un éditeur soigneux, serait bienvenue.

Comment: Il n'y en a pas. C'est une de ces choses qui n'ont pas aucune explication.